# Determining asymptotic bounds on $T(n) = \sqrt{n}T(\sqrt{n})+n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Note: this is from JeffE's Algorithms notes on Recurrences, page 5:

http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/notes/99-recurrences.pdf

(1). So we define the recurrence $T(n) = \sqrt{n}T(\sqrt{n})+n$ without any base case. Now I understand that for most recurrences, since we're looking for asymptotic bounds, the base case wouldn't matter. But in this case, I don't even see where we could define the base case. Is there any number we are guaranteed to hit as we keep taking square roots starting from any integer Do we just define $T(n) = a$ for $n<b$, for some reals $a$, $b$?

(2). On page 7, Erickson gets that the number of layers in the recursion tree L will satisfy $n^{{2}^{-L}} = 2$. Where is this coming from? I have no idea. I see that the number of leaves in each level of the tree should sum to $\sqrt(n)\sqrt(n) = n$, but I have no idea where to go from there.

(3). From the result mentioned in (2). Erickson derives $T(n) = \theta(n\lg\lg(n))$. But unrolling the recurrence yields 
     $$T(n) = n^{\sum\limits_{i=1}^k  \frac{1}{2^{i}}}T(n^{\frac{1}{2^k}})+kn \leq (k+1)n $$

For any integer k. Wouldn't this mean $T(n) = O(n)$, contradicting $T(n) = \theta(n\lg
\lg(n)$? Where is my reasoning wrong? (Please know that I ask with complete confidence that it is wrong).

This is also posted on the computer science stack exchange, because of the overlap in topics.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding (2), the number of layers in the tree is the number of square roots you need to apply to $n$ until you get to $2$. That is, you want $L$ such that $n^{(1/2)^L} = 2$; note $(1/2)^L = 2^{-L}$.

Regarding (3), I think the $k$ will be the number of layers in the recursion tree, so according to (2) it will be $k = \lg \lg n$.

Comment: Also, thank you for answering my question.

Comment: (1). So your base case is 2? Could I with equal legitimacy take 1.5, or any number greater than 1 as my base case? I believe this would lead to the same asymptotic- we would just say $n^{(\frac{1}{2})^l } = 1.5$. Is there anything special about 2? (2). Are we defining $T(a) = constant$ for $a<2$ (or whatever base case is used)?

Comment: @J.B.G. I am not quite sure how to answer (1), so I will defer to others more knowledgeable than me. I don't know why the author chose $2$, but my guess is that it is the smallest integer larger than $1$. But you are right in that it is arbitrary, and your suggested fix (let $T(x) = c$ for all $x < 2$) seems reasonable.